# IE 8 CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I'm tring to set the style on the first div inside a fieldset and it doesn't seem to be working on IE 8. I've tried several different scenarios :first, first-child, etc and can't get it to work. Was wondering if anyone has any suggestion on getting it to work with IE 8? Thanks!

Here's what I have so far. CSS:

```
.partialViewContainer > fieldset > div:first-child {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="partialViewContainer">
  <fieldset>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: for me it works for ie8 http://jsfiddle.net/cHzmS/ do you declare `doctype` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the demo it is working, please verify your code once again may be you are missing some thing or any HTML markup problem try to validate your code.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rywe4/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rywe4/embedded/result/

Try to use Markup validation service: http://validator.w3.org/